# Retrieve values from custom form in ASPxGridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a custom edit form made for ASPxGridView but have a big problem retrieving the values when inserting.

The template:

```
<Templates>
    <EditForm>
        Company Name: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="CompanyName" runat="server" />
        Company Mail: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Email" runat="server" />

        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="UpdateButton" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton" runat="server" />
        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="CancelButton" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton" runat="server" />

    </EditForm>
</Templates>
```

it fails, the e.NewValues are empty

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
{
    string CompanyName = (string)e.NewValues["CompanyName"]; // (or .toString())
    string Email = (string)e.NewValues["Email"];
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The e.NewValues collection is empty because you did not bind editors to data.  To make your code work, it should be changed as follows:

```
Company Name: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="CompanyName" runat="server" Value="<% #Bind('CompanyName')%>"/>
Company Mail: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Value="<% #Bind('Email')%>"/>
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I my controls are already bound by using #Bind. What I noticed is that only the controls that are inside my ASPxPageControl lose their values. Their values won't be sent through e.NewValues not matter what I do.

@DevExpressTeam

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to assign the NewValues to a string.  The RowUpdatingEvent seems like a better event to get the NewValues; you would also have access to the OldValues.  Check it out: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowUpdatingtopic